# Calling a procedure returns "success" but nothing has changed in base

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-call-interface

I'm trying to call a stored procedure from a php page, but I'm not getting the result I want.

I'm using oci with php, the query execution looks like this:

```php
function executeQuery($c, $query){
    $stid = oci_parse($c, $query);
    if (!$stid) {
        $e = oci_error($c);
        trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    $response['success'] = oci_execute($stid);
    if (!$response['success']) {
        $e = oci_error($stid);
        $response['error'] = $e;
        return $response;
        trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    //oci_commit($c); //auto commit is by default with oci_execute but I've tried this too. 
    oci_free_statement($stid);
}
```

**If my** `$query` **is an insert, it work fine** and commits the insert, but when it's `CALL MY_PROC('VAR1`, 'VAR2', VAR3'), `$response['success']` is true but nothing has changed on the database.

And if I execute `CALL MY_PROC('VAR1', 'VAR2', VAR3')` **in TOAD**'s editor and commit, **it works as expected** I can see the results on the database. But not when I call my procedure from php.

I've tried using `EXECUTE` instead of `CALL`, adding `COMMIT;` at the end of the query, and `oci_commit($c)` it still not impacts the database.

- What am I doing wrong? Is this likely to be a commit problem?
- What can I do to get errors instead of a "success"?
- Do procedures calls behave differently than inserts and selects, maybe?

The stored procedures calls a package that I didn't write myself and has **out parameters**, could that be why I'm not getting errors? (Again when I run it in toad with the same values it works fine, and show no error in particular).

My procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MY_PROC(
    VAR1 IN VARCHAR2,
    VAR2 IN VARCHAR2,
    VAR3 IN VARCHAR2
  )
  IS

  BEGIN
    ERROR_CODE := NULL; --//inherited from the packages, don't really know what do do with them
    ERROR_MSG := NULL;

    IF VAR2 = NULL THEN
      VAR2 := 'DEFAULT';
    END IF;
    PKG_USER.CREATE_USER(VAR1, VAR2, VAR3, ERROR_CODE, ERROR_MSG);

    IF (ERROR_CODE != NULL OR ERROR_MSG != NULL) THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR_CODE : ' || ERROR_CODE);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR_MSG: ' || ERROR_MSG);
      RAISE PROGRAM_ERROR; --//tried doing this to catch the errors but doesn't work
    END IF;
  END;
/
```

I guess part of the problem is with those error out parameters, but again it works fine with no error when I run in it TOAD.

**EDIT**: I just realised that if I try to call a procedure that **doesn't exist**, like `CALL MYY_PROC()` **it still doesn't return an error**, and returns "success".

Another thing to note is that I'm calling a number procedures on **different databases**. On all the other bases but this one, I get errors normally and calling a proc that doesn't exists rightfully returns:

`ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name`

So IMO it can either be 2 things: copy-paste mistakes (that I'm checking right now) or some database settings like @cdb_dba mentioned.

---

*Btw the platform I'm developing this for uses php4. Obviously not my choice, don't ask.*

Comment: Make sure that you are connecting to the correct DB

Comment: It appears that a COMMIT is not occurring after you execute your stored procedure.

Comment: @asiby Thanks. Yup I am, as I said an `INSERT` works and I can see the effect on the base

Comment: Two things to check: 1. Make sure server output is on. You can do this by adding `set serveroutput on;` to the beginning of your procedure. Add it right before your CREATE OR REPLACE statement. 2. Are you signing into Toad using the same schema that calls the procedure from the php page? You should see errors if the application schema doesn't have permissions to call the procedure, but it's worth looking into. 

You might also want to add the commit to your procedure at the end of your IF case. Applications like Toad do a lot in the background, and it might be auto committing your changes.

Comment: Instead of `call my_proc` please try `begin my_proc; end;`. [Calling Oracle Stored Procedures with PHP](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/fuecks-sps-095636.html)

Comment: @cdb_dba Yes, same schema. I tried adding a commit inside the proc, it didn't work.

Comment: replace this condition: `ERROR_CODE != NULL OR ERROR_MSG != NULL` whith this one: `ERROR_CODE IS NOT NULL OR ERROR_MSG IS NOT NULL`. anything != NULL always evaluates to NULL (false), so the IF statement and RAISE statement is never executed.

Comment: @cdb_dba See my edit, does that seem like something related to `serveroutput`?

Comment: Most likely not. serveroutput is related to the output of the DBMS_OUTPUT package. The setting controls whether the output generated by the DBMS_OUTPUT package is printed on the terminal. Not sure why you wouldn't get an error when trying to call a procedure that doesn't exist.. that's a new one for me. It might be related to the exception handling on the application side? I'm guessing it always displays an error from Toad, so I would look into how exceptions/errors are being handled. Break points will be your friend here.

Comment: @cdb_dba Ok I found my error... like all the problems that seem unsolvable, it was the stupidest of errors. Should I delete my question then?

Comment: In retrospect, simple issues might seem stupid, but trust me when I say that you are not the first person that has solved a problem like this, and you will not be the last. If someone's comment has helped you solve the error, I would encourage them to post their comment as the answer so that you can mark it as such. That way, when another new enterprising developer runs into a similar issue, they might run across your question and it can be helpful to them as well. :) We all start from somewhere, just look at my question history if you don't believe me, lol! Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I feel stupid but as it turns out, if your `$query` variable is `null`, `oci_execute` will always return success.

My variable wasn't called `$query`: I had set (and echoed for confirmation) `$queryProcFTTx`, but I executed `$queryProcFttx`. I was tricked by VSCode that highlighted both when I double-clicked the variable, ignoring case.